# How to replace a whitespace before number using Replace method?

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace a whitespace before a digit using java method ReplaceAll? How should i create a regex to make it?

Here is an example:

I want to change:

```
John 9:50
Steve 12:30
Luke Peter 14:44
```

To:

```
John\t9:50
Steve\t12:30
Luke Peter\t14:44
```

Comment: You mean `\t` as a tab character, right? Not a literal backslash, followed by `t`?

Comment: I would avoid using tab in this situation as you can run into poorly formatted output if a name is much longer or shorter than the others, but rather would use a Formatter or `String.format(...)` (basically the same thing).

Comment: For example, I would split on `(?=\\d)`, and then would use `String.format("%xs %yx", myTokens[0], myTokens[1])` where x and y are values needed to assure proper spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a job for a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(" (?=\\d)", "\t");
```

If you meant *any* kind of whitespace (including tabs, newlines, formfeeds etc.), use `\\s` instead of the simple space I used here.

Answer (score 1):

```
String newStr = oldStr.replaceAll(" (?=\\d)","\\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

No one else has suggested this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\d)", "\\t");
```

This replaces *any number* of whitespace characters before a digit with a tab char.

The other answers all replace only the *last* whitespace before a digit, possibly leading to multiple tabs in the final string.